# How to handle "HTTPException raise" during "message.attachments" deletion

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

My auto-moderation contains a @Cog.listener() that checks if the message contains an image in attachments. If it does, it will automatically get deleted(to avoid NSFW stuff).

The problem is that, the above event, triggers an other listener as shown below:

```py
@Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        embed = Embed(title="Message deletion",
                      description=f"Action by {message.author.display_name}.",
                      colour=message.author.colour,
                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

        fields = [("Content", message.content, False)]

        for name, value, inline in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

        await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Since the initial msg(with the img attached) does not contain a value it raises "HTTPException: 400 Bad Request" which is also triggering my error handler.
You can see the whole error log and my error handler in the following link : [bin](https://mystb.in/ReviewedEmbeddedNarrative.python)

I've been struggling for hours to find a way that will prevent my `on_message_delete` from firing up but I got nothing. I don't really care if the deleted attachments wont get reported in my log. I just want to prevent the errors from being populated.

Any suggestion/ideas will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could add another if statement which checks to see if there is an attachment with that message? If the issue is that the message has no content, just add an if statement to check for that. E.g. `if message.content == None: message_content = "No Content"`

Comment: If the message got deleted, ``message.content`` is an empty string instead of `None`. Thanks a lot for your answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
message_content = message.content if message.content else "No Content"
fields = [("Content", f"{message_content}", False)]
```

The above worked for cases that content got deleted(therefore is an empty string)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a deleted message's content. This is why you are getting http error.